# How to run SVN command with crontab

Tags: linux, shell, svn, cron

I have write a shell script

**cd /var/www/html/myprj/

svn status | grep [?] | grep .php$ | grep -v temp | sed 's/^?     //'  | xargs rm -rf

rm -rf /var/www/html/myprj/index.php

svn update /var/www/html/myprj/

chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/myprj**

I have using **contab -e** to run shell script
***/1 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /var/www/html/myprj/sch.sh**

The result is: 
**O**  cd /var/www/html/myprj/
**X**  svn status | grep [?] | grep .php$ | grep -v temp | sed 's/^?     //'  | xargs rm -rf
**O**  rm -rf /var/www/html/myprj/index.php
**X**  svn update /var/www/html/myprj/
**O**  chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/myprj

All the SVN command are not run with crontab
But I really confirm the shell script can run. (/**usr/bin/sh /var/www/html/myprj/sch.sh**)

please help me to run the svn command in crontab. 
Thanks all.

Comment: You don't need /usr/bin/sh in the crontab entry, simply add #!/usr/bin/sh to the top of your script.

Comment: Do you get an error message? `crontab` usually uses a restricted PATH: Is `svn` installed in one of the usual places or do you need to specify the full path to the executable?